# Query first sentence of an HTML paragraph field in SQL Server / Access front end

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I have been trying to find how I can query the first sentence only of a paragraph within a field (HTML code) for SQL Server but I am unable to find how. I have found solutions for MySQL using the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and I have also found solutions returning a certain number of words/characters but not using a specific delimiter.

My field is stored as HTML, an example is as follows:

```
<html><body>Enter the following page information.<br><br>
<b>Display #:</b> 1 [Automatically Populated]<br>
<b>Start Page: </b> 1 [Automatically Populated]<br>
<b>DCI Name:</b>  DEMOG<br>
<b>Clinical Planned Event:</b>  BASELINE1<br>
<font color="#0070C0">TAKE A SCREENSHOT</font>.<br>
</body></html>
```

In this example, I am hoping to only return/query "Enter the following page information" and not the rest of the paragraph. I'm assuming the HTML break might be the best delimiter as some sentences may end in a colon.

Thank you in advance! I hope I explained the scenario well enough.

Comment: Oy, why is HTML output like that stored in the database?

Comment: This is driven by a web-based application, specifically: HP Quality Center.

Comment: Heh, I'm not envious. :) Looks like you've got a good solution to try though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is ugly as sin, but assuming that the first `<br>` is the end of the line, this should work in the SQL Server back-end:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(200)
SET @x = '<html><body>Enter the following page information.<br><br><b>Display #:</b>'

SELECT substring(@x,

    (charindex('<br>', lower(@x)) - 1) - 
        (charindex('>', REVERSE(LEFT(@x, charindex('<br>', lower(@x)) - 1))))+2,

    charindex('>', REVERSE(LEFT(@x, charindex('<br>', lower(@x)) - 1))) - 1

)
```

Basically, we find the *last* instance of `>` in the string before the first `<br>`, and then find the `<br>` at the end, and take the difference between the two for the length.

This could absolutely be written cleaner in a function, but I opted to go with pure T-SQL to avoid using functions.

A final note:  You may not need the `lower` functions; my test database is case-sensitive, therefore the need to make the casing consistent.

Comment: Thanks - however this appears to be static for the one example I provided. I have many rows of data that have different HTML paragraphs (different words, some end in a colon, full stop.. etc) I am primarily looking for a dynamic way to return only the first sentence of the paragraph for reporting purposes. Although to complicate it further I just realized that if I did just pull the first sentence up to the HTML break it won't convert nicely to Rich text on my report since it won't have the closing HTML statements to keep it clean. YOY!

Comment: I don't see it as static; the query finds the text between the first `<br>` and the last tag before the `<br>`. This should strip out the leading `<html><body>` in the first example.  The intent was to replace the hard-coded `@x` variable by using this in a a `SELECT` statement.  Have you tried it with different values to see the results?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I responded to quickly - I'll try this on different values and get back to you! thanks!

Comment: This is perfect - it does exactly what I need! Thank you so much!